# querySelectorAll обработка в функции

Tags: javascript, функции, queryselectorall

Делаю обработчики для меню, получается так, что обрабатываю множество событий на различные селекторы.
Получаю все элементы через класс с помощью querySelectorAll();
На выходе что-то подобное:

```js
let elem1 = document.querySelectorAll("elem-class-1 > li > a");
let elem2 = document.querySelectorAll("elem-class-1 > li > a");
let elem2 = document.querySelectorAll("elem-class-1 > li > a");

for (let i = 0; i < elem1.length; i++) {
    elem1[i].addEventListener("click", funcClick1);
}

for (let i = 0; i < elem2.length; i++) {
    elem2[i].addEventListener("click", funcClick2);
}

for (let i = 0; i < elem3.length; i++) {
    elem3[i].addEventListener("click", funcClick3);
}

function funcClick1(e) {
    ...
}
function funcClick2(e) {
    ...
}
function funcClick1(e) {
    ...
}
```

Само собой напрашивается решение для обработки querySelectorAll и тут я делаю такое:

```js
function handlerSelectors (paramElem, paramHandler) {
    for (let i = 0; i < paramElem.length; i++) {
        paramElem= paramElem[i];
        paramElem.addEventListener(paramHandler)
    }
}
```

Чтобы просто собирать селекторы тогда когда мне нужно и подписывать на клик, используя нужный обработчик:

```js
handlerSelectors(elem1, funcClick1);
handlerSelectors(elem2, funcClick2);
handlerSelectors(elem3, funcClick3);
```

Тоска начинает одолевать в тот момент, когда данной функцией я пробегаюсь по 2+ элементам. Например, если у меня есть:

```
<ul class="elem-class-1">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

И я использую ту самую функцию, то получаю только первый ul li a, а хочется все.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Для начала исправьте ошибки синтаксиса: `.length` вместо`.lenght`, `paramElem.length` вместо `elem.lenght`, ...

Comment: @skolm И названия повторяющихся функция и элементов.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Внесено много правок от опечаток до названия функций.
Но формируя функцию таким образом Вы привязываете ко всем нажатиям элементов с тегом "a" одно и тоже действие. (Ко всем нажатиям элементов с тегом `a` класса `.elem-class-1` привязываете одно и тоже действие - в примере вывод `123`, для всех элементов `a` класса `.elem-class-2` вывод функции `2` и так далее.)

Пример:

```js
    let elem1 = document.querySelectorAll(".elem-class-1 > li > a");
    let elem2 = document.querySelectorAll(".elem-class-2 > li > a");
    let elem3 = document.querySelectorAll(".elem-class-3 > li > a");
    function handlerSelectors (paramElem, paramHandler) {
        paramElem = Array.from(paramElem);
        for (let i = 0; i < paramElem.length; i++) {
            elem = paramElem[i];
            elem.addEventListener('click', paramHandler)// Но таким образом Вы привязываете ко всем нажатиям элементов с тегом "a" одно и тоже действие.
        }
    }
    function funcClick1(e) {
        console.log('123');
    }
    function funcClick2() {
        console.log('3');
    }
    function funcClick3() {
        console.log('345');
    }
    handlerSelectors(elem1, funcClick1);
    handlerSelectors(elem2, funcClick2);
    handlerSelectors(elem3, funcClick3);
```

```html
<ul class="elem-class-1">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="elem-class-2">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="elem-class-3">
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, ваше примечание верно и это именно та логика которая необходима.

Спасибо.

Comment: @skolm, Нет, он не критичен. можно использовать просто `paramElem[i].addEventListener('click', paramHandler);`